# Is there any method forwarding event from UIButton to UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, drag

I want to forward event from button which in the scrollview to scrollview when the button touched down and dragged inside.

by Using button's "addTarget: action: forControlEvent" function, I can receive button down and drag event and also can move scrollview as I dragged.

But the problem is the scroll view doesn't react like origin scrollview's scroll. This means there is no accelerate animation when I finish dragging.

I'm looking for the method forwarding event to scrollView so that the scrollview can react as it dragged on itself even though the event from the button on the scrollview.

Is there anyone who knows this?

Comment: I couldn't find this.. but I solved this using some trick.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679191/iphone-how-to-scroll-uiscrollview-from-event-touched-by-uibutton-in-scrollview/10753694#10753694